# Question Regarding Glassfish WAR-Deployment Problem

Tags: jsf, deployment, glassfish, war

I am using Glassfish 5.0.1/4.1.1 for a Webproject (JSP, JSF, Bootsfaces, JPA). There I encountered the problem, that Glassfish is not allways building the Website correctly.

Sometimes it is build normally how it should be (Pic 1) and sometimes there are elements missing (Pic 2). This does even happen when deploying the same WAR-File.

Can anyone help with this problem?

**Pic 1 - Normal Deployment:**

[image: Pic 1 - Normal Deployment]

**Pic 2 - Problem:**

[image: Pic 2 - Problem]

Source Code (XHTML):

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Statustool</title>
    </h:head>
    <f:view>
        <h:body>
            <div class="container" name="main" style="margin-top: 50px" >
                <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
                    <b:image name="/img/Logo.png" span="6" offset="3"/>
                    <b:row styleClass="show-grid">
                        <b:column span="4" offset="4">
                            <h3 style=" text-align: center"><h:outputText value="Statustool Anmeldung" /></h3>
                            <b:form id="loginForm">
                                <b:inputText id="inputEmail" value="#{loginBackingBean.loginUser.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Email muss eingegeben werden" label="Mail"/>
                                <b:message for="inputEmail" />

                                <b:inputSecret id="inputPasswort" value="#{loginBackingBean.loginUser.userPassword}" required="true" requiredMessage="Passwort muss eingegeben werden" label="Passwort"/>
                                <b:message for="inputPasswort"/>

                                <b:commandButton value="Anmelden" action="#{loginBackingBean.login()}" />

                            </b:form>
                        </b:column>
                    </b:row>
                    <ui:include src="public/footer.xhtml"/> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
```

Comment: Are there Exceptions with stack traces printed to log files in case of (Pic 2)? Best chance for anyone to help you is providing a [mcve].

Comment: And debug, investigate, do what a developer would do.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no related Stack Trace Error for this Problem (I would have tried to google that myself in that case). Reproductable is a bit of a problem, because as I described it is possible to Deploy one and the same wAR-File multiple times, sometimes the error occurs, sometimes it does not.


The xhtml file is showed below, sometimes the middle part just is missing in the viewable source code.

Comment: I would very much do debugging but I am clueless what. Because as I said the error seems to appear sponanous without any warning or indication why - at least not any I could find (believe me I would like to debug and google my problem because it is very annoying to redeploy the stuff multiple times in the hope one does work).